# How to write this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

i have this problem with javascript and jQuery and was wondering if i could get some help to rewrite this javascript to jQuery? =)

```
 var url = location.href.split('#');
 var active = url[1];
 if(active == "home") { 
 /* code */
 }
 else if(active == "blog") { 
 /* code */
 }
```

Comment: That would be exactly the same... jQuery is just a JavaScript library which simplifies DOM manipulation. It does not add anything regarding string manipulation or flow control (apart from deferred objects maybe).

Comment: Define, "this problem." What do you want to happen? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Seems like one of those misunderstandings that jQuery is something other than a library on top of JavaScript. You have no DOM manipulation here, no AJAX calls, just a tiny bit of boolean logic.

Comment: the problem is that the javascript code i have wont work inside an jquery code, so if i could rewrite this.. or?

Comment: @Daniel If it doesn't work, then your additional JavaScript which utilizes jQuery is wrong.

Comment: ok, i'l have some more look at it... but thx. =)

Comment: You can access the anchor with location.hash and avoid the split and accessing the position 1 of the array

Comment: I dont know what was wrong.. (lol).I uploaded the code again, and now it seems to work!.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) instead?

```
switch (window.location.hash.substr(1)){
  case 'home':
    // code
    break;
  case 'blog':
    // code
    break;
}
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` will contain the `#` as well though ;)

Comment: Yea, I know. Was just about to fix it (had to step away from desk briefly before I could). Thanks for the heads though, Felix. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you have it. jQuery isn't a replacement for JavaScript, it's just an extension.

Comment: Yes, that is what i though to. But i had this other jquery code that would not work when it was inside those if/else's.. probably something wrong with the other code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is, primarily, a DOM manipulation and Ajax library. It is not loaded down with functions for fiddling with URIs or even strings. I don't think there is anything in core jQuery that would improve the code in the question.